# Character(0) error when using rvest to webscrape Google search results

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, google-search

I am trying to scrape the headers of the Google search. However, doesn't matter what I try with `rvest`, the result always returns `character(0)`.

Here is the code for the search `rstudio`:

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

web1 <- read_html("https://www.google.at/search?q=rstudio") 
header <-web1 %>%
    html_nodes(".DKV0Md") %>%
    html_text()
header
```

The node name I checked in `SelectorGadget`, so that shouldn't be an issue. How should I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, we can use:

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
web1 %>% 
   html_nodes(xpath = '//div/div/div/a/div[not(div)]') %>% 
   html_text
```

Output:

```r
#[1] "rstudio.com"        
#[2] "rstudio.cloud"           
#[3] "en.wikipedia.org › wiki › RStudio"    
# ....
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, Akrun! But do you maybe have a clue why the initial code with the class name (and not xpath) didn't work?

Comment: @AlinaZamaletdinova `class` is unstable in google search

Comment: Just in case if someone faces the same issue, here is the code which worked for me and which returns the headers: 
`library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
web1 <- read_html("https://www.google.at/search?q=munich+prices") 
web1 %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '//div/div/div/a/h3/div[not(div)]') %>% 
  html_text`