# Web-Scraping Search Result

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to scrape a google search result but my element keeps showing up empty. Here is my code:

```
url = ("https://www.google.com/search?q=most+popular+place+in+france&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS875US875&sxsrf=AOaemvIURBlj0HQnAmvIlMyjdcP1WPeh5Q%3A1637686399981&ei=fxydYc2IO42jqtsPkZOVuAw&oq=most+popular+place+in+fr&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMYADIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgYIABAWEB4yCQgAEMkDEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjoECCMQJzoFCAAQkQI6CwguEIAEEMcBENEDOggIABCABBCxAzoLCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6EQguEIAEELEDEIMBEMcBEKMCOgsILhCABBCxAxCDAToECC4QQzoFCC4QgAQ6CwguEIAEEMcBEK8BOgsILhCABBDHARCjAjoECAAQQzoHCAAQyQMQQzoKCAAQgAQQhwIQFDoICAAQyQMQkQI6DQgAEIAEEIcCELEDEBQ6CwgAEIAEELEDEMkDOgUIABCSAzoICAAQgAQQyQNKBAhBGABQAFiBJGDlLGgBcAJ4AIAB8QGIAa8ckgEGMC4yNC4xmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz")
first_page <- read_html(url)
titles <- html_nodes(first_page, xpath = "///div[1]/div/div/span/div[1]/a/div/div[2]/span[1]") %>% 
  html_text()
```

I have searched "most popular place in france" into google and am only trying to scrape in the "Eiffel tower" search result. Please help.

Comment: Your xpath isn't pointing to a real object - the /div[1] that you've chosen doesn't have an immediate /a attribute, so the html_nodes returns an empty nodeset that is coerced into an empty character vector by html_text. It's unclear what you mean by "the eiffel tower search result" so I can't help fix the pathing.

Comment: To scrape google results you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70291641/obtaining-character0-error-when-using-rvest-to-get-google-results-headlines/70292356#70292356 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64407669/character0-error-when-using-rvest-to-webscrape-google-search-results?answertab=oldest#comment113897251_64407755