# Obtaining "Character(0)" error when using rvest to get Google results headlines

Tags: r, web-scraping, google-search

Sorry if my question is simple or badly asked, I am very new at web scraping with R.

I am trying to scrape the headlines from a Google search. Sorry if it is exactly the same request previously asked in the link below, however it does not work for me (it still returns
"character(0)"    ).

[Character(0) error when using rvest to webscrape Google search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64407669/character0-error-when-using-rvest-to-webscrape-google-search-results?answertab=oldest#comment113897251_64407755)

Here is the two scripts I tried, based on the answers provided in the link above:

#Script 1

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
web1 <- read_html("https://www.google.at/search?q=munich+prices")  
web1 %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = '//div/div/div/a/div[not(div)]') %>% 
    html_text
```

#Script 2

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr) 
web1 <- read_html("https://www.google.at/search?q=munich+prices")  
web1 %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = '//div/div/div/a/h3/div[not(div)]') %>%
    html_text
```

The two scripts still return "character(0)" for me.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks you for your help.
Victor

Comment: Script 2 worked fine

Comment: It is against Google's [Webmaster Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/webmaster-guidelines) and [terms of service](https://policies.google.com/terms/archive/20020906?hl=en) to submit programmatic search queries. Running this code against Google is likely to cause Google to show captcha for searches from your IP address.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I found out that it depends on the region where you make the request from. I tried to launch the request using a VPN for several regions in the world, and it worked! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested here is the screenshot,

```
   library(rvest)
    library(dplyr) 
    web1 <- read_html("https://www.google.at/search?q=munich+prices")  
    web1 %>%
        html_nodes(xpath = '//div/div/div/a/h3/div[not(div)]') %>%
        html_text
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I found out that it depends on the region where you make the request from. I tried to launch the request using a VPN for several regions in the world, and it worked! :)