# Read table with columns of unequal row length by filling with NA

Tags: r, dataframe

I am failing to a read a table with read.csv() as it has columns of different row lengths.

My data looks like this:

```
      x        y

1     cat      small
2     dog      medium
3     mouse
```

I want to fill out the shorter columns with NA, so that I can create a data frame looking like this:

```
      x        y

1     cat      small
2     dog      medium
3     mouse    NA
```

The read.scv documentation has an argument "Fill=TRUE", but this function only deals with tables having rows of different column lengths.

Best regards,
Rikki

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide reproducible example. On how to ask one refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64407669/character0-error-when-using-rvest-to-webscrape-google-search-results?answertab=oldest#comment113897251_64407755

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try fread from the data.table package. This recognizes empty cells and fills them with NA.

**The csv I've created for testing looks like:**

```
a;b
1;1
2;2
3;3
;4
;5
```

**R Code:**

```
library(data.table)

fread(file.choose())
```

**Output:**

```
    a b
1:  1 1
2:  2 2
3:  3 3
4: NA 4
5: NA 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Option one in baseR:

```
df[df==""]<-"NA"


     x      y
1   cat  small
2   dog medium
3 mouse     NA
```

or option two you could use `dplyr()`

```
library(dplyr)

mutate_all(df, list(~na_if(.,"")))

      x      y
1   cat  small
2   dog medium
3 mouse     NA
```

Sample data